# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified when I run pyspark in cmd/Pycharm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run a python file in pycharm with below code. I am facing the same issue when I give pyspark in cmd as well as pycharm, could somebody please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Code :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType, DecimalType, IntegerType
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("ETL").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
source_data_file = "C:\Python_pgms\apache-spark-etl-pipeline-example-master\apache-spark-etl-pipeline-example-master\data\20160104\*"
print("Fetching")
```

Facing below issue :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python_pgms/apache-spark-etl-pipeline-example-master/apache-spark-etl-pipeline-example-master/src/etl.py", line 5, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("ETL").getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 186, in getOrCreate
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 376, in getOrCreate
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 133, in __init__
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 325, in _ensure_initialized
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 98, in launch_gateway
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Looks like it can't find the Spark executable. Check your `PATH` etc.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee. I am able to run spark scala using same configurations. Not sure, why isn't it starting for python. Please let me know if I need to modify anything...Path =C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin;C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;F:\Scala\bin

Answer (score 0):

pycharm-> run -> edit configuations -> environment variables

add PYTHONPATH and SPARK_HOME according to your path